# Need some assistance on replacing a light fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I am attempting to replace my light fixture. This is a basic question but am I mounting the crossbar correctly?  I always thought the little holes were for the fixture to attach to.  Is that wrong?

Or should I be utilizing the small holes for the larger screws?

With the setup pictured I am having issues attaching the light through the key hole slots (step 4 in the manual attached) The screws seem to be too short.

Should I get longer screws or am I doing something incorrectly?

[image: Current Setup]

Below is the manual if that helps.

http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/822985510455_install.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a couple of measurements.

1. Check the distance between the long screws as you have them set right now and compare to the distance between the key hole slots on the fixture base. They need to be the same.
2. Measure the depth from the panel that the keyhole slots are in to the top most rim of the fixture base. This distance needs to be a little less than the long screw head protrusion below the ceiling surface. The installation guide says that the protrusion needs to be about 1.2 inches. If screws are too short maybe you pre-installed them into the box holes too far .. or you will have to acquire longer screws.

Make sure to connect the GND wire from the fixture base to the bare wire safety ground wires in the electrical box.

The cross bar installation looks OK but it is not doing much for you.

Comment: I would say you covered it all, especially the part about the bracket not doing a lot. I don't see it being needed at all as long as the bolts line up with the keyhole slots. As long as the ground wire in the fixture can be tied to the ground wire in the box, that is all that is needed that I can tell. The plastic box will not need grounded.

Comment: Is my junction box an odd style?
I think according to the manual I am supposed to use the smaller holes to mount the fixture.

Problem is there isn't room to use the small screws with the plate as the junction box gets in the way.

The old plate I had will work but was just curious if I had the wrong style ceiling box?

Comment: Adapter plates come in a variety of styles. Electrical boxes also have variation. Put those two together and it is not surprising that the dimensions or features of one or the other may have conflicts. If you really want to use a metal adapter plate in this box you could consider getting one of these:  https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Metallic-Box-Accessories-Mounting-Brackets-Universal/Dottie/SP34/product.aspx?zpid=674218